# Externally scoped variables in IronPython delegates

Tags: delegates, scope, ironpython

In IronPython, I can't seem to get a variable from outside a delegate's scope to change (or even appear) inside its scope. This is contrary to what I can do in both C# and Python.

In C#, I could do the following (contrived) example:

```cs
public delegate bool Del(int index);

public static void Main() {
    int itemTally = 0;

    Del d = delegate (int index) {
        itemTally += 3;
        return true;
    };
        
    for (int i = 4; i < 6; i++) {
        d.Invoke(i);
    }

    Console.WriteLine(itemTally);  // prints 6
}
```

I can do the same thing in Python:

```py
item_tally = 0

def delegate(index):
    global item_tally
    item_tally += 3

for x in range(4, 6):
    delegate(x)

print(item_tally)  # prints 6
```

but changing a Python variable in a Python delegate *called by C#* will crash:

```cs
public class BatchProcessor {
    public delegate bool Del(int index);

    public static int ProcessBatches(Del the_delegate) {
        int batchTally = 0;
        for (int i = 4; i < 6; i++) {
            the_delegate(i);
            batchTally++;
        }
        return batchTally;
    }
}
```

```py
import BatchProcessor
item_tally = 0

def delegate(index):
    global item_tally
    item_tally += 3  # "global name 'total_count' is not defined"
    return True

batch_tally = BatchProcessor.ProcessBatches(BatchProcessor.Del(delegate))

print(item_tally)
```

Is there a way to increment `total_count` in the Python delegate without changing any C#?

Comment: Could you provide more info on the crash? Could you show if/how/.. the python code is parsed and the degeate/scope/engine is managed/kept alive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding an extra `global` line to the IronPython in the scope outside the delegate got it working. That line wasn't necessary in the Python-only version:

```cs
public class BatchProcessor {
    public delegate bool Del(int index);

    public static int ProcessBatches(Del the_delegate) {
        int batchTally = 0;
        for (int i = 4; i < 6; i++) {
            the_delegate(i);
            batchTally++;
        }
        return batchTally;
    }
}
```

```py
import BatchProcessor
global item_tally  # Adding this line made it work.
item_tally = 0

def delegate(index):
    global item_tally  # You need to keep this line, too.
    item_tally += 3
    return True

batch_tally = BatchProcessor.ProcessBatches(BatchProcessor.Del(delegate))

print(item_tally)  # prints 6
```